# Eclipse : How can i know that to what package does a class belong to?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE

How can i know that to what package does a class belong to ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover over the classname. Information about the class should appear in a tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `package` statement at the top.